# Google Sheets - Query from selected tab

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have multiple tabs with the same structure, and a query tab. There, I am using the following query formula:

```sql
=query({'Sheet1'!A2:L},"select * "&
IF(COUNTA(B2:B3)>0,"where "&
IF(B2="","","Col"& COLUMN('Sheet1'!B2) &" >= date '" & TEXT(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd") &"'")&
IF(B3="","",IF(COUNTA(B2)>0," and ","")&"Col"&
COLUMN('Sheet1'!B2) &" <= date '" & TEXT(B3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"),""),1)
```

I have set cells B1:B3 with data validation:

1. B2 will select the start date for the query
2. B3 will select the end date for the query

I would like that B1 would determine the tab from which the query would select the data.
For example, if `B1` value is `Sheet1`, the query would select the data from `Sheet1`, and only show the data from `Sheet1`. If it is set as `Sheet2`, it would select from `Sheet2`, and so on.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the INDIRECT() function

[image]

```
=query(indirect(B5),"SELECT *",1)
```

[image]